# Use `parallel` option of `boot` function in `R`

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I was using `boot` function in `R` to implement bootstrap. My question is how to set `boot` to exploit its parallel option. Consider the following concrete example of estimating median.

```
med_est <- function(dat, indices){
    .dat <- dat[indices]
    median(.dat)
}
dat <- rnorm(200)
system.time(boot(dat, med_est, R = 10000))
system.time(boot(dat, med_est, R = 10000, parallel = "multicore"))
```

I don't know how to use the `parallel` option in `boot` function. Letting `parallel = "multicore"` does not boost the speed at time. I have tried more complicated estimation problems. But I did not see the difference. So I guess I did not use `boot` correctly. My machine is double-core Mac.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `boot` manual (bolding is mine).

> boot(data, statistic, R, sim = "ordinary", stype = c("i", "f", "w"),
>   strata = rep(1,n), L = NULL, m = 0, weights = NULL,
>   ran.gen = function(d, p) d, mle = NULL, simple = FALSE, ...,
>   parallel = c("no", "multicore", "snow"),
>   **ncpus = getOption("boot.ncpus", 1L)**, cl = NULL)

try:

```
system.time(boot(dat, med_est, R = 10000, parallel = "multicore", ncpus=2))
```

Comment: In addition, you may need to do something like `library(doMC); registerDoMC(detectCores())`, or whichever parallel package you like.

Comment: @Chris the `boot` manual says that it loads the `parallel` namespace which is already a combination of `snow` and `doMC` so loading the library won't be necessary.  `boot` does give the option to specify a cluster but the manual says if the user doesn't specify it that it will create a cluster.  I think OP's problem is that the default `ncpus` is 1L instead of `detectCores()`.